# Solr error adding data to spatial field (without any clue)

Tags: solr

I get an error without any further clues what went wrong when adding data to the field definded like this:

```
  <fieldType name="timeframe_spatial"
       class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
       geo="false"
       worldBounds="0 0 1999999999999 1999999999999"
       distErrPct="0"
       maxDistErr="1"
       units="degrees"/>
```

This is the error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=57602f13-273c-4adc-b9de-8cdf0c49fdd8] Error adding field 'opentime'='[1464782400000 1464804000000,​ 1464868800000 1464890400000,​ 1464955200000 1464976800000,​ 1465027200000 1465063200000,​ 1465113600000 1465149600000,​ 1465214400000 1465236000000,​ 1465300800000 1465322400000,​ 1465387200000 1465408800000,​ 1465473600000 1465495200000,​ 1465560000000 1465581600000,​ 1465632000000 1465668000000,​ 1465718400000 1465754400000,​ 1465819200000 1465840800000,​ 1465905600000 1465927200000,​ 1465992000000 1466013600000,​ 1466078400000 1466100000000,​ 1466164800000 1466186400000,​ 1466236800000 1466272800000,​ 1466323200000 1466359200000,​ 1466424000000 1466445600000,​ 1466510400000 1466532000000,​ 1466596800000 1466618400000,​ 1466683200000 1466704800000,​ 1466769600000 1466791200000,​ 1466841600000 1466877600000,​ 1466928000000 1466964000000,​ 1467028800000 1467050400000,​ 1467115200000 1467136800000,​ 1467201600000 1467223200000,​ 1467288000000 1467309600000,​ 1467374400000 1467396000000,​ 1467446400000 1467482400000,​ 1467532800000 1467568800000,​ 1467633600000 1467655200000,​ 1467720000000 1467741600000,​ 1467806400000 1467828000000,​ 1467892800000 1467914400000,​ 1467979200000 1468000800000,​ 1468051200000 1468087200000,​ 1468137600000 1468173600000,​ 1468238400000 1468260000000,​ 1468324800000 1468346400000,​ 1468411200000 1468432800000,​ 1468497600000 1468519200000,​ 1468584000000 1468605600000,​ 1468656000000 1468692000000,​ 1468742400000 1468778400000,​ 1468843200000 1468864800000,​ 1468929600000 1468951200000,​ 1469016000000 1469037600000,​ 1469102400000 1469124000000,​ 1469188800000 1469210400000,​ 1469260800000 1469296800000,​ 1469347200000 1469383200000,​ 1469448000000 1469469600000,​ 1469534400000 1469556000000,​ 1469620800000 1469642400000,​ 1469692800000 1469728800000,​ 1469779200000 1469815200000,​ 1469865600000 1469901600000,​ 1469952000000 1469988000000,​ 1470038400000 1470074400000,​ 1470124800000 1470160800000,​ 1470211200000 1470247200000,​ 1470297600000 1470333600000,​ 1470384000000 1470420000000,​ 1470470400000 1470506400000,​ 1470556800000 1470592800000,​ 1470643200000 1470679200000,​ 1470729600000 1470765600000,​ 1470816000000 1470852000000,​ 1470902400000 1470938400000,​ 1470988800000 1471024800000,​ 1471075200000 1471111200000,​ 1471161600000 1471197600000,​ 1471248000000 1471284000000,​ 1471334400000 1471370400000,​ 1471420800000 1471456800000,​ 1471507200000 1471543200000,​ 1471593600000 1471629600000,​ 1471680000000 1471716000000,​ 1471766400000 1471802400000,​ 1471852800000 1471888800000,​ 1471939200000 1471975200000,​ 1472025600000 1472061600000,​ 1472112000000 1472148000000,​ 1472198400000 1472234400000,​ 1472284800000 1472320800000,​ 1472371200000 1472407200000,​ 1472457600000 1472493600000]' msg=Index: 0,​ Size: 0
```

and this is the stack trace:

```
msg=Index: 0, Size: 0
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:176)
    at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:169)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:49)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:924)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:702)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:251)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:156)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2073)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:457)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:222)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.tree.QuadPrefixTree.getCell(QuadPrefixTree.java:153)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.tree.LegacyPrefixTree.getTreeCellIterator(LegacyPrefixTree.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.tree.QuadPrefixTree.getTreeCellIterator(QuadPrefixTree.java:42)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.PrefixTreeStrategy.createCellIteratorToIndex(PrefixTreeStrategy.java:170)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy.createCellIteratorToIndex(RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy.java:126)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.PrefixTreeStrategy.createIndexableFields(PrefixTreeStrategy.java:152)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.PrefixTreeStrategy.createIndexableFields(PrefixTreeStrategy.java:147)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.prefix.PrefixTreeStrategy.createIndexableFields(PrefixTreeStrategy.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.AbstractSpatialFieldType.createFields(AbstractSpatialFieldType.java:212)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:123)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this value tuple:

```
<field name="opentime">1472130000000 1472162399000</field>
```

I I raise or lower these values (even just 1) it works.

After fiddling around - a "solution" is to change the world boundaries from:

4102444799000 -> 2272147200000

But it's not clear and logical why this is working...